# Search multidimensional arrays for specific keys and output their data

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have following array construction: `$array[$certain_key][some_text_value]`

And in a while loop, I want to print the data from the array, where `$certain_key` is a specific value.

I know how to loop through multidimensional arrays, which is not the complete solution to this problem:

```
foreach ($a as $v1) {
    foreach ($v1 as $v2) {
        echo "$v2\n";
    }
}
```

I do not want to loop the whole array each time, but only when `$certain_key` is matched.

**EDIT:** to be more exact, this is what I'm trying to do:

```
$array[$array_key][some_text];

while reading from db {

  //print array where a value returned from the db = $array_key

}
```

Comment: You got a lot of possible solutions, each is valid for different situations.  You should be more precise with your questions to narrow down the answers you receive.

Comment: @Benjamin: ok, thank you... I will update it now... did not expect so much help so quickly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($array as $certain_key => $value) {
    if($certain_key == $row['db_id']) {
        foreach ($value as $some_text_value) {
            echo "$v2\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while ($row = fetch()) {
   if (isset($array[$row['db_id']])) {
      foreach ($array[$row['db_id']] as $some_text_value => $some_text_values_value) {
         echo ...
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: omg... thank you! this looks very promising, I will try it! Thank you for a practical sample!!

Answer (score 1):

You mean like

```
foreach($array[$certain_key] as $k => $v)
{
     do_stuff();
}
```

?

Comment: Are you checking to see if the key exists?  Look at  `array_key_exists()`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/array_key_exists)? It works like this:

```
if(array_key_exists($certain_key, $array)) {
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

foreach ($a as $idx => $value) {
    // replace [search_value] with whatever key you are looking for
    if ('[search_value]' == $idx) {
        // the key you are looking for is stored as $idx
        // the row you are looking for is stored as $value
    }
}
```